# Can't display fa-folders icon in vuetify

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuetify.js, font-awesome

I use [Vuetify](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/) and font-awesome icons. It works pretty good, but 'fa-folders' icon is not visible:

.ts file:

```
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome'
import { fas } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import { far } from '@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons'

Vue.component('icon-fa', FontAwesomeIcon)
//@ts-ignore
library.add(fas, far)
```

.vue file:

```
<icon-fa
  style="font-size: 19px;"
  v-on="on"
  :icon="['fas','fa-folders']"
  class="mr-0 theme--light v-icon">
</icon-fa>
```

dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
  "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.35",
  "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.15.3",
  "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.3",
  "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome": "^0.1.10"
 }

"devDependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.15.3"
}
```

I have error in console:

> Couldn't find one or more icon(s) {prefix: 'fas', iconName: 'fa-folders'}

Comment: I think it should be `fa-folder` instead of `fa-folders` ?

Comment: @RohìtJíndal these are two different icons https://fontawesome.com/v5/icons/folders?s=solid

Answer (score 0):

Please use this CDN link inside your import for checking its working or not! If  working then problem exist in your file path.

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css
```